# Calculate overlap of two datetime objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, datetime

I would like to find out how much time lays in between 22.00 and 6.00 o’clock for a given event per day.

So if the event start at 21.00 and ends at 23.59 the result would be 1.59. For a start at 22.00 and end at 7.00 it would be 2.00 + 6.00 = 8.00 hours. So basically I want to calculate the night shift part per day.

I came up with the following implementation. It works but I wonder if there is an easier way that uses less overhead/ lines of code.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time
from typing import Dict, Generator


def daterange(start_date: datetime, end_date: datetime) -> Generator[datetime, None, None]:
    for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)


def get_overlap(dt1: datetime, dt2: datetime) -> timedelta:
    # Check that the two datetimes are on the same day
    if dt1.date() != dt2.date():
        raise ValueError('Datetimes must be on the same day')

    # Calculate the start and end times of the two periods of interest
    early_shift_start = datetime.combine(dt1.date(), time(hour=0))
    early_shift_end = datetime.combine(dt1.date(), time(hour=6))
    late_shift_start = datetime.combine(dt1.date(), time(hour=22))
    late_shift_end = datetime.combine(dt1.date(), time(hour=23, minute=59, second=59))

    # Calculate the amount of overlap between the two periods
    overlap = max(min(dt2, early_shift_end) - max(dt1, early_shift_start), timedelta())
    overlap += max(min(dt2, late_shift_end) - max(dt1, late_shift_start), timedelta())
    return overlap


def split_on_midnight() -> Dict[str, float]:
    start_date = datetime(2023, 3, 1, 12, 30, 0)  # example start datetime
    end_date = datetime(2023, 3, 3, 16, 45, 0)  # example end datetime

    total_duration = timedelta()
    for date in daterange(start_date, end_date + timedelta(days=1)):
        midnight = datetime.combine(date, time.min)
        chunk_start = max(start_date, midnight)
        chunk_end = min(end_date, midnight + timedelta(days=1) - timedelta(seconds=1))
        if chunk_start < chunk_end:
            duration = get_overlap(chunk_start, chunk_end)
            total_duration += duration
            print(f"Chunk from {chunk_start} to {chunk_end}: {duration}")

    return {"total_duration": total_duration.total_seconds() / 3600}


print(split_on_midnight())
```

Answer (score 4):

**Set up your code for ease of testing**. This is useful both for your own
debugging and when asking others for help or code review. Instead of writing an
English paragraph giving us example inputs and expected outputs (or hardcoding
a single example in your program), organize the entire program for ease
of testing and experimentation, from the ground up. In any project of
significance, I would do that with a testing tool (I like pytest, but there are
other good options as well). In a simple situation like an online code review,
including a `main()` method with a simple testing apparatus works fine, as
shown below.

**Speaking of testing, the example in your code has a bug**. Given
`datetime(2023, 3, 1, 12, 30, 0)` and `datetime(2023, 3, 3, 16, 45, 0)`, your
code returned 57598 seconds. But the answer should be 57600 seconds: 28800 +
28800 (two 8-hour night shifts, one for 3/1 to 3/2 and the other for 3/2 to
3/3). I did not try to track down the source of the bug, because my overall
reaction to your code was the following: it's looks like the code has been put
together in a thoughtful way, but there is a lot of complexity in it, and my
gut tells me there is a simpler way to address the problem (your question text
makes me think that your gut was telling you something similar).

**If something is a datetime, don't call it a date**. You have a few variables
that are misnamed in that fashion: `start_date` and `end_date` are the two most
prominent examples. This may seem pedantic (indeed it is), but conceptual
clarity is rewarded in programming in the form of fewer bugs, more readable
code, and more efficient communication with others working on a project (this
becomes even more true as projects grow in size and complexity). If it's a
datetime, don't call it a date; if it's a dict, don't call it JSON (the later
is text); and vice versa. Often, one can achieve greater clarity simply with a
different naming convention: for example, `start` and `end` are shorter names,
completely clear in context, and don't imply anything incorrect about their
underlying nature.

**An alternative approach**. My idea for this problem was to maintain a tiny
list of datetimes. The list would initially contain the input start and end
times, plus the upcoming start or end point for the next night shift. Sort the
list in reverse order. Pop off the most recent datetime. If the
current start and the popped item
cover the night shift, add their duration to the total. As needed, add another night shift
endpoint to the list and sort again. Stop when the tiny list no longer contains
the input end time.

I started with some constants:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time

NIGHT_START_TIME = time(22, 0)
NIGHT_END_TIME = time(6, 0)
```

Then a function to take the input start and yield appropriate night shift
endpoints in the future:

```
def nightshift_endpoints_gen(start):
    start_date = start.date()
    combine = datetime.combine
    n = 0
    while True:
        dt = combine(start_date + timedelta(days = n), NIGHT_START_TIME)
        if dt > start:
            yield dt
        n += 1
        yield combine(start_date + timedelta(days = n), NIGHT_END_TIME)
```

With those building blocks, computing the overall duration is not
too bad:

```
def nightshift_duration(start, end):
    dts = [end, start]
    e = start
    gen = nightshift_endpoints_gen(start)
    tot = 0
    while end in dts:
        dts.append(next(gen))
        dts.sort(reverse = True)
        s, e = (e, dts.pop())
        start_time = s.time()
        if start_time >= NIGHT_START_TIME or start_time < NIGHT_END_TIME:
            tot += (e - s).total_seconds()
    return int(tot)
```

And a testing apparatus:

```
def main():
    TESTS = (
        # Example from your code.
        (
            datetime(2023, 3, 1, 12, 30, 0),
            datetime(2023, 3, 3, 16, 45, 0),
            16 * 3600,
        ),
        # Examples from your comments.
        (
            datetime(2020, 2, 28, 21, 0, 0),
            datetime(2020, 2, 28, 23, 59, 0),
            119 * 60,
        ),
        (
            datetime(2020, 2, 2, 22, 0, 0),
            datetime(2020, 2, 3, 7, 0, 0),
            8 * 3600,
        ),
        # A time span entirely within the night shift.
        (
            datetime(2020, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0),
            datetime(2020, 2, 3, 5, 5, 0),
            125 * 60,
        ),
    )
    for start, end, exp in TESTS:
        got = nightshift_duration(start, end)
        if got == exp:
            print(got, 'ok')
        else:
            print(got, exp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**An alternative approach: solve directly**. A different idea is to solve
directly rather than iterating over all days from `start` to `end`. The idea
here is to decompose the total duration into three chunks: (1) the partial
night shift that `start` might be part of, (2) the partial night shift that
`end` might be part of, and (3) the full night shift(s) that might sit in
between all of that stuff.

```text
# Five night shifts (equal signs), plus start and end (carets).

========    ========    ========    ========    ========
   ^                                               ^

# The chunks:
Chunk 1: start to the first night-shift-end.
Chunk 2: the last night-shift-start to end.
Chunk 3: three full night shifts.
```

To solve the problem along those lines, we could use a function that can take a
datetime and return its closest "neighbor" to the right (future) or left
(past), where a neighbor is a night shift startpoint or endpoint. We can use
that function to compute the partial chunks (1 and 2) and to find references
points to compute the number of full night shifts in the middle chunk (we will
always use night shift starts for that purpose). To handle all of that we can
break down the situation into three possibilities:

```text
# Notation

dt : datetime
NS : night shift startpoint
NE : night shift endpoint
|| : midnight

# Three possibilities:

NE  dt  NS            #1: dt is not in a night shift
NS  dt  ||  NE        #2: dt in night shift, before midnight
NS  ||  dt  NE        #3: dt in night shift, after midnight
```

Start with some constants:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time

NS = NIGHT_START_TIME = time(22, 0)
NE = NIGHT_END_TIME = time(6, 0)

NON_NIGHTSHIFT = 0
BEFORE_MIDNIGHT = 1
AFTER_MIDNIGHT = 2

LEFT, RIGHT = (0, 1)

SAME_DAY = timedelta(0)
NEXT_DAY = timedelta(1)
PREV_DAY = timedelta(-1)

NEIGHBOR_PARAMS = {
    # in_nightshift() : [LEFT neighbor,  RIGHT neighbor]
    NON_NIGHTSHIFT    : [(SAME_DAY, NE), (SAME_DAY, NS)],
    BEFORE_MIDNIGHT   : [(SAME_DAY, NS), (NEXT_DAY, NE)],
    AFTER_MIDNIGHT    : [(PREV_DAY, NS), (SAME_DAY, NE)],
}

SECONDS_PER_NIGHTSHIFT = 8 * 3600
```

Then two utility functions, one to determine a datetime's night shift status
and another to return the "neighbor" to the right or left:

```
def in_nightshift(dt):
    t = dt.time()
    return (
        BEFORE_MIDNIGHT if t >= NIGHT_START_TIME else
        AFTER_MIDNIGHT if t < NIGHT_END_TIME else
        NON_NIGHTSHIFT
    )

def neighbor(dt, direction):
    params = NEIGHBOR_PARAMS[in_nightshift(dt)]
    td, time = params[direction]
    return datetime.combine(dt.date() + td, time)
```

And finally, our primary function and its immediate helper to find the relevant
neighbor and associated chunk #1 or #3.

```
def nightshift_duration(start, end):
    ns1, chunk1 = get_nightshift_startpoint(start, True)
    ns2, chunk2 = get_nightshift_startpoint(end, False)
    chunk3 = (ns2 - ns1).days * SECONDS_PER_NIGHTSHIFT
    return int(chunk1 + chunk2 + chunk3)

def get_nightshift_startpoint(dt, is_start):
    if in_nightshift(dt):
        if is_start:
            dt2 = neighbor(dt, RIGHT)
            ns = neighbor(dt2, RIGHT)
        else:
            dt2 = ns = neighbor(dt, LEFT)
        chunk = abs((dt - dt2).total_seconds())
        return (ns, chunk)
    else:
        ns = neighbor(dt, RIGHT)
        return (ns, 0)
```

I suppose this approach is "better" in the sense that it can immediately
compute any duration, even if `start` and `end` are millions of days apart
[after typing this I looked up the max year supported by datetime, and it is
shockingly low, so I guess Python has low expectations for humanity]. But it
was definitely harder to think through all of the details of this approach.
Whether the resulting code is easier or harder to understand than my
first approach is a close call. In its first draft, the new approach was definitely
harder to understand, but it got better as I added more
constants, so I guess that's my final piece of advice: **use
constants and data structures to simplify coding logic and
enhance readability**.